# How to only load web fonts as a backup

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fonts

I am making a portfolio in React and on mobile my local font doesn't load. I would like to make it so that if the local font doesn't load, then I fetch the google font that looks similar. If the local font loads, then I don't want to have the google font load. How can I do this with React

I have tried loading it no matter what, but I think it would be more efficient to load the font as a backup

I would use something like this in plain JavaScript but don't know the React equivalent.

```
if(document.getElementById('header').style.fontFamily != "local-font") {
    var fontLink = document.createElement('link');
    fontLink.href = "http://myGoogleFont.com";
    fontLink.rel = "stylesheet"
    document.body.appendChild(fontLink);
}
```

Sorry if this is basic, but I'm a beginner with React

Comment: No reason you couldn't use same thing

Comment: can't you not directly manipulate the DOM with React?

Comment: Would append to head but otherwise won't affect react app. It only runs in whatever element it is bootstrapped to